# How to write Batch script to do something based on windows version

Tags: excel, batch-file

I am fairly new to writing batch scripts and our system has just thrown me a slight curve ball.

We are getting new computers with Windows 10 and Office 16.  We also still have Windows 7 and Office 14 PCs are the network that have not been upgraded yet.

I currently have a batch file that does an xcopy on execution that checks an excel file on a server against a version of the same file on the users local machine.  If the server version is newer, it copies over the local version then opens and runs the excel file.

I need to update my batch to accomodate both versions of excel when it needs to open and run the file.

I can check either on windows or excel version as they are married together, but I'm open to whichever method is more reliable.

I was playing with WMIC which returns the version of windows reliably on our machines.  I tried other scripts from my research on the web and they did not function as I would have liked.

Here is my current code:

```
set "source=\\s001\FOLDER\EXCELFILE TOOL.xlsm"
set "target=C:\Apps\EXCELFILE TOOL PROGRAM\"

xcopy "%source%" "%target%" /y /d /h /k /r

START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe" /e "%target%\EXCELFILE TOOL.xlsm"
EXIT
```

Before the "START" line, I need to check which version of windows or office is on the machine, then modify the start to be one of these two options:

Option 1

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe" /e "%target%\EXCELFILE TOOL.xlsm"
```

Option 2

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.exe" /e "%target%\EXCELFILE TOOL.xlsm"
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I am not understanding where the Windows Version comes into play?

Comment: why not just do `where /R "c:\Program Files" excel.exe`

Comment: @Squashman We are deploying new PCs that have Windows 10 and Office 2016 installed as a shared image.  If the user is on Windows 10, they also are on Office 2016.  If the user is on Windows 7, they are on Office 2013.  The windows version was just another method to check for which version of excel to call.  If I can just make it check the version of excel and fire the appropriate script, I do not have to worry about the version of windows.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Can you explain what /R what do in this instance wherein it is a solution to my issue, thanks!

Comment: It will recursively search for the file and return the path found. From cmdline do `where /?` for more info on that.

Comment: Something like `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /R "c:\program files"') do "%%a"` which should launch excel from the path.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Ok, I see how that returns the path needed.  How would i write the syntax to use the where function to start excel and open the file as noted in option 1 or 2 above

Comment: Like the comment i just gave. If that does not work add excel.exe after %%a like. `%%a\excel.exe`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I still do not follow, when I try that line of code, it is not constructed to fire as I would like.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I get %%a was unexpected at this time, also the excel file is in "Program Files (x86)", but I undertstand your point and changed the statement you wrote accordingly.  Nonetheless, it still is not getting me there.

Comment: Are you running it from cmdline or batch file?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Running from cmdline to test

Comment: Then both instances should be %a instead of %%a

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Can you write the whole statement, my apologies for not following as quickly as I am getting syntax errors.  I will run from the batch, but I need to see the whole statement.  This includes opening excel with the file listed above.

Comment: I am on my phone. So please give me the entire output when you run the `where /r` line please. Then i will write it for you.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard When i run `WHERE /R "c"\Program Files (x86)" excel.exe` it returns `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE`

Comment: Then do from cmd line `for /f "delims=" %a in ('where /R "c:\program files (x86)"') do start "" "%a"`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I get `ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default argument is missing.`

Comment: You shouldn't need to know, where or what Excel is installed. Both `"%target%\EXCELFILE TOOL.xlsm"` or `start "" "%target%\EXCELFILE TOOL.xlsm"` should open the file in it's default application (which should be Excel)

Comment: I am on my laptop now to post an answer, but @compo already added the correct code at the bottom of his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to start `Excel`, searching directories should be unnecessary.

Once installed `Excel` would have a registry sub-key created under:

```bat
"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE|HKEY_CURRENT_USER]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths"
```

Most likely named:

```bat
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Excel.exe"
```

Where the `Default` value data holds the fully qualified path to the application.

With entries under this key, simply entering the applications name should run it:

```bat
Start Excel.exe
```

The `REG_SZ` data entry can be used with or without its `.exe` extension.
*(If necessary, the ShellExecuteEx function adds the extension when searching App Paths subkey)*.

You could therefore simply use:

```bat
Start Excel
```

---

If using the method suggested throughout the majority of the comments then you'd need to use `Excel.exe` as part of your search mask!

The example below, utilises an additional `For` loop, to allow for checking in both `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`

```bat
@For %%A In ("%ProgramFiles%" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" 2^>Nul
) Do @For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('Where /R %%A Excel.exe 2^>Nul'
) Do @Start "" "%%~B"
```

You could of course ignore the outer loop if you're sure that the installed version is always installed to `Program Files (x86)`.

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" Excel.exe 2^>Nul'
) Do @Start "" "%%~A"
```

The above two examples could be left as one line, if you're not interseted in maintaining lines of no more than `80` characters.

Comment: Thanks for the input, how would I incorporate the opening of the actual excel file as well.  I want it to open the excel file, not just the excel program.

Comment: _@GrahamDredt, I'm not entertaining such a question. If you don't know how to open a file with a program using the command line, then you need more than the type of help this site offers!_

Comment: I appreciate your help and I'm sorry you feel that way.  I thought this site was about imparting knowledge to those with less, but as it appears I have reached your limit, I appreciate your time nonetheless.

Comment: I was able to get the batch to work based on Campo's post.  I simply needed to just use `START Excel` instead of `"" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe"`.  This lets excel fire irregardless of the version.  Thank you all.